# C# : Seconds to Minutes to Hours conversion?

Tags: c#, data-conversion

Okay first off, I'm pretty sure I'm not expected to use TimeSpan for this assignment; rather a formula series which shows the seconds, minutes, and hours in a message box when the user enters the number of seconds in the text box.

Here's where I'm stuck. We're supposed to check our answers with the example: 7565 seconds is 2 hours, 6 minutes, and 5 seconds. However, my code ends up calculating it as 2 hours, 6 minutes, and 6 seconds. It also keeps that answer when the initial number is 7560 seconds. I'm so confused!! It's a conditional scenario, in which the message box shows only the seconds if the user enters under 60 seconds, only minutes + seconds if the user enters between 60 and 3600 seconds, and hours + minutes + seconds if over 3600 seconds is entered.  Here is what I have so far, and I'd appreciate any insight as to why my calculation is off :)

Thanks for the answers! But the 7565 isn't a constant; the user can enter any amount of seconds but my professor used 7565 as an example to check if we're on the right track.

```
private void calculateButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int totalSeconds, hours, minutes, minutesRemainder, hoursRemainderMinutes, hoursRemainderSeconds;
        totalSeconds = int.Parse(secondsTextBox1.Text);
        minutes = totalSeconds / 60;
        minutesRemainder = totalSeconds % 60;
        hours = minutes / 60;
        hoursRemainderMinutes = minutes % 60;
        hoursRemainderSeconds = hoursRemainderMinutes % 60;

        if (totalSeconds < 60)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(totalSeconds.ToString());
        }

        else if (totalSeconds < 3600)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(minutes.ToString() + " minutes, " + minutesRemainder.ToString() + " seconds");
        }

        else if (totalSeconds>3600)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(hours.ToString() + " hours, " + hoursRemainderMinutes.ToString() + " minutes, " + hoursRemainderSeconds.ToString() + " seconds");
        }

    }
```

Comment: This may be an answer to your question but you can do this: `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7565).ToString()`. This will return `"02:06:05"`.

Comment: OP stated he didnt think he was supposed to use a TimeSpan. but it is the simplest way :P One thing to point out is your if-elsif block ... what do you get when you enter 3600 total seconds? it is nether less than or greater than 3600.

Answer (score 10):

Try using *modular* arithmetics

```
int totalSeconds = 7565;

int hours = totalSeconds / 3600;
int minutes = (totalSeconds % 3600) / 60;
int seconds = (totalSeconds % 60);
```

...

```
if (hours > 0)
  MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} hours, {1} minutes, {2} seconds", hours, minutes, seconds));
else if (minutes > 0)
  MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} minutes, {1} seconds", minutes, seconds));
else
  MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} seconds", seconds));
```