# unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' in c#

Tags: c#, timer

I have created a timer app with n number of instances. when i tried to run that app it is showing me an error saying "unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'"

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer = new Timer();

            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(t_Tick);

            panel.Add(AddNewPanel());
             panelId++;
        }
```

my code for t_tick event:

```
private void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button c = (Button)sender;
            Class1 t = findButtonByTag(c.Tag.ToString());
            if ((minutes == 0) && (hours == 0) && (seconds == 0))
            {
                timer.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("Times up"); 
                t.totalSeconds.Enabled = true;
                t.totalSeconds.Text = "";
                //label12.Text = "";
                started = true;
                t.pause.Enabled = false;
                t.start.Text = "Start";
                t.time_in_hour.Text = "00";
                t.time_in_minutes.Text = "00";
                t.time_in_seconds.Text = "00";

            }
            else
            {
                //calculating the seconds that are being passed
                if (seconds < 1)
                {
                    seconds = 59;
                    if (minutes == 0)
                    {
                        minutes = 59;
                        if (hours != 0)
                            hours -= 1;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        minutes -= 1;
                    }
                }
                else
                    seconds--;


                if (hours < 10)
                    t.time_in_hour.Text = "0" + hours.ToString();
                else
                    t.time_in_hour.Text = hours.ToString();
                if (minutes < 10)
                    t.time_in_minutes.Text = "0" + minutes.ToString();
                else
                    t.time_in_minutes.Text = minutes.ToString();
                if (seconds < 10)
                    t.time_in_seconds.Text = "0" + seconds.ToString();
                else
                    t.time_in_seconds.Text = seconds.ToString();

            }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you have `Button c = (Button)sender;` in your event ? it is the timer which is sender, not your button.

Comment: If there was ever an argument for test-driven development, it's code like this. Please, plase, please pause and think about what you are trying to achieve and start again.The fact that you are trying to cast a Timer object to a Button object is the least of this code's problems.For example, look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/25802379/7122 for clues as to how to just count down seconds and format an HH:MM:SS display, rather than the way you are doing it.

Answer (score 0):

It's the `Timer` invoking the `t_Tick` event rather than the `Button`. Fix it by using the `Timer` as the sender rather than the `Button`

Comment: Well, this will fix the error, but the remainder of the code will never compile after this fix. That code need a total rewrite.

Comment: @Steve Most of it should. The only reference to the `sender` object is here: `Class1 t = findButtonByTag(c.Tag.ToString());` so it entirely depends on what `Class1` does which code was not provided.

Answer (score 0):

this is class code

```
public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {
            this.panel = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.label1 = new Label();
            this.time = new Label();
            this.time_in_hour = new Label();
            this.time_in_minutes = new Label();
            this.time_in_seconds = new Label();
            this.colon1 = new Label();
            this.colon2 = new Label();
            this.start = new Button();
            this.totalSeconds = new TextBox();
            this.pause = new Button();
            this.delete = new Button();
            this.countTimers = new Label();
        }

        public Label countTimers { get; set; }
        public System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel { get; set; }
        public Label label1 { get; set; }
        public Label time { get; set; }
        public Label time_in_hour { get; set; }
        public Label time_in_minutes { get; set; }
        public Label time_in_seconds { get; set; }

        public Label colon1 { get; set; }
        public Label colon2 { get; set; }

        public TextBox totalSeconds { get; set; }
        public Button start { get; set; }

        public Button pause { get; set; }

        public Button delete { get; set; }
    }

}
```